# in operator in parametrized sql query

Tags: java, mysql

i want to search from a set using parametrized sql query for a particular value wheteher it conatin or not than what will be the sql query for this

Comment: On what platform, in what language, using what library? Please show some code and add meaningful tags

Comment: java,mysql  PreparedStatement search = conn.prepareStatement("select p.DEALER_NAME from DEALER_PROFILE as p,DEALER_DOMAIN as d,DELER_PROFILE_DOMAIN as pd where d.DOMAIN_ID = pd.DOMAIN_ID and d.DOMAIN_NAME =? and  pd.DEALER_ID= p.DEALER_ID    ")  ;here i want to check domain name from string array if user have even one domain then it should be include in result

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know prepareStatement can't use comma delimited lists for `IN()` clause.
You can use something as simple as:

```
private static final domainListPlaceHolder =  "<DOMAINS_LIST>";

String sql = "select p.DEALER_NAME from DEALER_PROFILE as p,DEALER_DOMAIN as d,
DELER_PROFILE_DOMAIN as pd where d.DOMAIN_ID = pd.DOMAIN_ID 
and d.DOMAIN_NAME IN (<DOMAINS_LIST>) and pd.DEALER_ID= p.DEALER_ID";

// build a comma delimited String from your array (each domain wrapped with ''), called domainList

String sqlToRun = sql.replace(domainListPlaceHolder, domainList);
```

Comment: is there any way searching aganist a component

Comment: @bhavishya: I am not sure I understand what you are asking? can you paste the code you want to use (even pseudo-code or code that does not work)?